# Unique parameterization for multi threaded group with single CSV file

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I am new to the jmeter community, and I am now working on a scenario in which the test plan contains 9 thread groups but we must utilize a single CSV file (we are not permitted to split the csv to multiple CSV files to distribute among the thread groups in the test plan as per client requirement), and we must pass unique values to the login.

We set CSV data set to global as we need to use single csv file alone for a script & CSV file has only username alone. we tried multiple ways but nothing seems working, one of the below example with groovy we tried but nothing seems working
${__groovy(new File('/filepath/file.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}

We must use a single CSV dataset for various thread groups while passing unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "multiple ways" you "tried" and how exactly they "are not working" but given you:

1. Put CSV Data Set Config on the same level as Thread Groups (see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules))
2. Set [Sharing Mode of the CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) to `All threads` and `Recycle` to `False`

each thread will read next line on each iteration without any duplicates:

[image]